# Calcular media aritmética de un Array con un length constante

Tags: javascript

La cuestión es calcular la media aritmética de un Array (que contiene un conjunto de valores numéricos) que tiene **un `length` FIJO** al que le llegan **nuevos valores**, en la respuesta explico todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es simplemente hacer una media aritmética de un grupo de valores en un Array al que se le van añadiendo valores, a lo que me refiero es hacer la media aritmética de un Array al que le **llegan nuevos valores sin cambiar su longitud** (de este modo **tendré que eliminar los valores más antigüos**), para explicarlo mejor:

Tenemos un Array con **longitud 10** lleno de ceros al que le vamos a ir añadiendo nuevos valores y eliminando los más antigüos:

`var array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`

Si metemos un valor (el 1 por ejemplo) ahora quedará así:

`var array = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`

Si agregamos un 2 ahora:

`var array = [1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];`

Si tenemos por ejemplo un Array lleno:

`var array = [3,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4];`

y le introducimos ahora el valor **45**, quedaría:

`var array = [45,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4];` y la media aritmética de este Array sería **9**;

Si a este último Array le añadimos el **56,** quedaría: 
`var array = [45,56,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4];` y su media aritmética sería **14.1**;

> Esto nos sería de mucha utilidad si queremos hacer una media de la
>   latencia (cliente-servidor) o por ejemplo una tasa de FPS, en este
>   caso el ejemplo es calculando el tiempo que tarda en calcular un
>   fotograma usando **`window.requestAnimationFrame`**:

```
var tope = 100; //Tope es la cantidad de valores que tendrá el Array
var array = new Array(); //Creamos el array
var sum = 0; //La suma de los valores
var voy = 0; //La posición en el Array
var n = 0; //La longitud del array que usaremos para evitar fallos cuando el array comienza vacío hasta que se llena
var oldDate, nowDate, diferencia, media; //Variables de fechas, etc

function llenarArray() {
    for (var i=0; i < tope; i++) {array[i] = 0;} //Lo llenamos de ceros
}
llenarArray();

var perm = false; //Esto es simplemente para que el primer valor no sea 0 justo la primera vez que se llama a la función

//Iniciamos la fecha antigua
oldDate = new Date();
oldDate = oldDate.getTime();

function mediaAritmetica() {

    //Tomamos la fecha actual
    nowDate = new Date();
    nowDate = nowDate.getTime();

    if (perm === true) { //Comprobación del perm para evitar lo que en la varibale perm he explicado

        diferencia = nowDate - oldDate; //Toamamos la diferencia entre los dos valores
        sum = sum - array[voy] + diferencia; //La suma actual menos la posición de voy en el array más el nuevo valor
        array[voy] = diferencia; //El valor de la diferencia lo metemos en el array en la posción voy
        voy++; //Voy indica la posición en el array, lo cual le sumamos 1

        if (voy > n) { //Cuando voy es mayor que n quiere decir que el array se está llenando
            n=voy; 
        }

        if (voy > tope - 1) { //Si voy es mayor que el tope de valores que hemos establecido voy volverá añ principio del Array
            voy=0;
        }

        media = sum / n; //Aquí es donde calculamos la media aritmética de ese conjunto de valores que hay en el Array

        console.log(array); //Mostrará el Array con los valores
        console.log(media.toFixed(2)); //Mostrará la media
    }

    perm = true;

    oldDate = nowDate; //La antigua fecha es ahora la nueva fecha

    //Para realizar la prueba podemos usar timeout o windowRequestAnimationFrame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(mediaAritmetica);
}

mediaAritmetica();
```

> **NOTA**: el ajuste de la **variable `tope`** varía/depende de los valores con los que estemos trabajando.

Se que algunos lo sabréis hacer y no os parecerá nada del otro mundo, pero para gente que empieza o pretenda hacer este tipo de cálculos lo veo bastante útil.

¡Espero que sirva de ayuda!